# Would a button to exit my iPhone app be in violation of Apple's guidelines?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I'd like to create a button in my iPhone app that quits the app (with `exit(0)`) when pressed. Would this be in violation of Apple's human interface guidelines?

Comment: Have you checked: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html ?

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry.  I'll have to hurry to select answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real need for this feature from a User Experience POV. Your app should gracefully shut itself down when the kernel asks it to, but otherwise, there's no reason for it not to be resident in memory, ready to re-launch at a moment's notice.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons not to stay resident.  Enhanced security of decrypted data on older devices, etc.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Counterpoint: 1Password does not kill itself whenever the user switches away. It locks itself up again. If that's not an app that's designed for security, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 8):

Apple discourages you from doing this and it's very likely you'd be rejected from the App Store. Also, this behavior is unnecessary. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it's not very likely, you **will** be rejected.  This is a blatant violation of the HIG, as described here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW1 (under Don’t Quit Programmatically)

Comment: @MattS. that link to the HIG seems broken. Do you know where that information exists now?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, yes. If the user wants to quit your app, they can always just press the home button -- you don't need to add an extra button that does the same thing.

Comment: Pressing the home button does not terminate all apps after iOS 4.x. It can leave them frozen in the background.

Answer (score 0):

It would be an unusual design choice, when compared with other iOS apps which follow the general convention of using the Home button to be placed into the background. I would not do the `exit(0)` trick, personally.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience (and from just checking the interface guidelines), I would think that it might be okay, but only if the user is the one triggering the exit.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely legal.  Apple even provides a documented plist key to force the OS to terminate your app when your app launches Safari (or any other registered URL).  All apps used to work this way before iOS 4.x