# Production code: display a message before calling abort/exit(-1)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uialertview

So this is related to core data exceptions. I know it is very unlikely, but if it occurs, and I cannot recover from the error, I want to call

```
abort();
```

However, before calling abort I want to show a message like

```
There is an unrecoverable error. The app is going to shut down.
```

How do I achieve that? Using alertView does not work, as the abort() is called before the app gets a chance to display the message.

Also at this point I want to block the thread from further execution of any code. It is almost like forcefully crashing the app..but doing it gracefully by displaying a message right before that.

Thanks
mbh

Comment: Did you put abort() in the button click event handler of your alert view?

Comment: No. That won't help as it would continue to execute rest of the code.The whole point of aborting is we are in unsafe waters. I cannot guarantee whats going to happen if I continue. So don't want to cause any data corruption. Lets force quit.

Comment: use a timer ,  display your message then countdown the timer , call **abort**

Answer (score 0):

Display alert view, call `return;`, then on the UIAlertView's button tap call `abort();`.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thought about that. If this is called from another function control just goes back to that function. Does not necessarily stop code execution.

Comment: Then have it return a bool. If yes,  the function that called it should call `return();`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `UIAlertView` and call `abort()` in its delegate, when the ok button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's almost always possible to recover from core data exceptions `[moc save:error]`. After unsuccesful save you can just do `[moc rollback]` - it should be quite enough to recover. Eventually you can forget all changes `[moc reset]`.

Answer (score 0):

Termination the execution of your app programmatically violates Apple's Human Interface Guidelines which will result in rejection of your app by Apple.

- [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: User Experience Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27)
- [ios - Would a button to exit my iPhone app be in violation of Apple's guidelines? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155157/would-a-button-to-exit-my-iphone-app-be-in-violation-of-apples-guidelines)