# Flutter how to programmatically exit the app

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I programmatically close a Flutter application.
I've tried popping the only screen but that results in a black screen.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

#### For iOS

**`SystemNavigator.pop()`**: Does **NOT WORK**

**`exit(0)`**: Works but Apple may **SUSPEND YOUR APP**

Please see:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html

---

#### For Android

**`SystemNavigator.pop()`**: Works and is the **RECOMMENDED** way of exiting the app.

**`exit(0)`**: Also works but it's **NOT RECOMMENDED** as it terminates the Dart VM process immediately and user may think that the app just got crashed.

Please see:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html

Comment: It looks like `SystemNavigator.pop()` is not working under Android emulator. The app is still working in background. So I am not sure if it will be working properly on real device.

Comment: @AleksTi It simply exits the app, it doesn't shut the VM process. You may try `exit(0)` for your need.

Comment: `SystemNavigator.pop()` exits my app and shows a message of crash, `exit(0)` works as expected

Comment: Is there a way, which works for both platforms and is recommended as well ?

Comment: @B.shruti There's no way to make an exit functionality in iOS. For Android, use `SystemNavigator.pop(...)`

Comment: "exit(0): Works but Apple may SUSPEND YOUR APP" - where does Apple state that in the guidelines? Please provide a link for this claim.

Comment: @tim-montague I didn't use the word **"will"**, I said **"may"**, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html), [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/application-rejected-apple-because-exit-button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155157/would-a-button-to-exit-my-iphone-app-be-in-violation-of-apples-guidelines)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad - My comment uses the word **"may"** - so, no argument there. Thanks for providing these links, I've edited your answer to include the archived document from Apple, but curious to know if recent Apple Guidelines still take this stance.

Comment: What about Desktop & Web (I think logically exit is incorrect here)?

Comment: For IOS, you can use with , NullSafety, this package  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_minimizer

Comment: At last I'm here to get rid of deprecation of `WillPopScope`....

Answer (score 228):

Below worked perfectly with me in both `Android` and `iOS`, I used `exit(0)` from `dart:io`

```
import 'dart:io';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new ... (...),
          floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: ()=> exit(0),
            tooltip: 'Close app',
            child: new Icon(Icons.close),
          ), 
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE Jan 2019**
Preferable solution is:

```dart
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

As described [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html)

Comment: that didn`t work for me... I`m trying to add an exit button to CupertinoTabScafold. With ()=>exit(0), it gives a blank screen with tabbar.

Comment: It works. But Apple prohibits custom exit buttons and will probably reject app if you have one

Comment: @HasanAYousef  In my solution get message Undefined name SystemChannels

Answer (score 53):

You can do this with [`SystemNavigator.pop()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html).

Comment: Nothing happens on both Android and iOS. Using `exit(0);` does work

Comment: On iOS, `SystemNavigator.pop` is ignored because Apple's human interface guidelines state that applications should not exit themselves. On Android, it should work, and is preferred over calling `dart:io`'s exit method. Consider filing an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Comment: Any idea for iOS how can we do in flutter ?

Comment: @iPatel You can use exit(0) for iOS, that's it.

Comment: Yo but what about rejection ;( as you told in above comment

Comment: You seems like an experienced iOS developer but that question from you surprised me. Actually you should neither let your user nor you should exit the app in iOS (weird). Apple will ban your app if you try to do so. Which is why I love Android :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Sorry for silly question I know that apple will reject the App. Actually i'm looking for Flutter but can't find any code for iOS, Above ans working in android perfectly. BTW thanks for your time and suggestion.

Comment: @iPatel Don't be sorry, it's no harm to ask question. And yes, don't use exit in your app for iOS part.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad - Where does Apple Human Guidelines state that apps can not exit programmatically?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad - The advice you give @iPatel in these comments, does not reflect the advice you gave me (in your answer, on this question thread). From the links you shared with me, the best I can gather is that ten years ago Apple discouraged the use of `exit`, and encouraged the use of showing the user a dialog so they could close the app if they wanted to do so. However, I do not know if this is Apple's current stance, as I'm unable to find any official mention of that in Apple's iOS guidelines.

Answer (score 52):

Answers are provided already but please don't just copy paste those into your code base without knowing what you are doing:

If you use `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');` note that [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html) is clearly mentioning:

> Instructs the system navigator to remove this activity from the stack
>   and return to the previous activity.
>
> On iOS, calls to this method are ignored because Apple's human
>   interface guidelines state that applications should not exit
>   themselves.

You can use `exit(0)`. And that will terminate the Dart VM process immediately with the given exit code. But remember that [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/exit.html) says:

> This does not wait for any asynchronous operations to terminate. Using
>   exit is therefore very likely to lose data.

Anyway the [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html) also did note `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`:

> This method should be preferred over calling dart:io's exit method, as
>   the latter may cause the underlying platform to act as if the
>   application had crashed.

So, keep remember what you are doing.

Comment: You wrote so many clever notes but... what the **correct way** to programmatically exit from app without potential suspension in iOS as described below?

Comment: Why `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` and not simply `SystemNavigator.pop();`?

Comment: @CsabaToth both are okay, using `invokeMethod` we are directly calling native android `pop` method. At that time Im writing may be flutter method `pop` did not exist. may be the `SystemNavigator.pop();` invoke native method to exit (Check the method source code, I havent checked it).

Answer (score 25):

you can call this by checking platform dependent condition. perform different action on click for android and ios.

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      SystemNavigator.pop();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      exit(0);
    }
  },
  child: Text("close app")
)
```

Answer (score 12):

I prefer using

```
 Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
        SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
      });
```

Although, exit(0) also works but the app closes abruptly and doesn't look nice, kind of seems that the app has crashed.

```
 Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
       exit(0);
      });
```

Answer (score 10):

the only solution I have seen so far, accepted in both stores is:

for android:

`SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');`

for ios:

there is no possibility of closing the app BUT you can move it to the background with https://pub.dev/packages/minimize_app like:

`MinimizeApp.minimizeApp();`

enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me;

```
import 'dart:io';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: new ... (...),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: ()=> exit(0),
        tooltip: 'Close app',
        child: new Icon(Icons.close),
      ), 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a mixin for the closing like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

mixin AppCloser {
  void closeApp() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      SystemNavigator.pop();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I just add it on the Page like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with AppCloser {
    ...

    child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => { closeApp() },
        child: Text('Close'),
    ),

    ...   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am calling *_getOutOfApp* function, this is not package;

```
    void _getOutOfApp {

      if (Platform.isIOS) {

        try {
          exit(0); 
        } catch (e) {
          SystemNavigator.pop(); // for IOS, not true this, you can make comment this :)
        }

      } else {

        try {
          SystemNavigator.pop(); // sometimes it cant exit app  
        } catch (e) {
          exit(0); // so i am giving crash to app ... sad :(
        }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use** `SystemNavigator.pop();` for **Android** and for **iOS** use `exit(0);`

here is example-

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
    exit(0);
    } else {
    SystemNavigator.pop();
            }
```

don't forget import `import 'dart:io';` on top

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Create a function, and in your `onPressed` function just call this function. Since `exit(0)` is not recommended by apple for `iOS` apps, I opted for this library here: https://pub.dev/packages/minimize_app.
Below is the code snippet:

```
void closeApp(){
   if(Platform.isAndroid){
       SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');            
   }else{
       MinimizeApp.minimizeApp();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can programmatically close the application by calling `SystemNavigator.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  SystemNavigator.pop();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically exit the app by calling the `SystemNavigator.pop()` method. This method is provided by the `services` package in `Flutter`, and it allows you to exit the current app and return to the home screen or the previous app.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void exitApp() {
  SystemNavigator.pop();
}
```

> **For iOS**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void exitApp() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  }
}
```

This code uses `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod` to invoke the `platform-specific` method for exiting the app on iOS. It essentially replicates the behavior of pressing the home button, and it's a less abrupt way to navigate away from your app.

Please use this method with caution and only when it's absolutely necessary, as unexpected app exits can lead to a poor user experience on `iOS`.

Answer (score 0):

Exit app. Remember, the animation only works in iOS.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

static Future<void> exitApp({bool? animated}) async {
  await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop', animated);
}
```

Flutter 3.16.4

Answer (score 0):

This is a working way to exit the application:

```
 static Future<void> pop({bool? animated}) async {
     await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void> 
     ('SystemNavigator.pop',animated);
 }
```