# How to close/kill app on Flutter

Tags: flutter, kill

I am actually aware of this implementation: [Flutter programmatically closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-programmatically-closing-the-app), but when the app closes is still in background. How can I absolutely kill the app and not let it be in background?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `exit(0);` in Android? In iOS there is no such thing as exiting an app.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes. In the description i told you i am aware of this, but doesn't work as i wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use `invokeMethod`, you can directly close the app using

```
SystemNavigator.pop(); // Only works on Android.
```

While `exit(0)` works on both iOS and Android, it shouldn't be used on either. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534684/6618622) for more information.

Comment: How do I exit and kill all the threads/processes  when user  manually kills the app?  In my flutter app(on Android) some processes which were meant to collect sensor data still run even after I close the app.  It only stops when I go on app info and do "FORCE STOP".

Comment: @Gauranga You can use `exit(0)` for that.

Comment: where do I call exit (0) . The onDespose methoes of UI are not called when user kill the app. I am wondering where should I call exit(0) . I want to release all the resources on exit call.

Comment: @Gauranga Can you post it as a question, I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: I hv asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854764/how-to-force-stop-flutter-app-when-user-kills-the-app

Answer (score 5):

You can use `exit(0)`. But app exits abruptly. You can use the below code which is much smoother.

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop')
```

Documentation is available [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Need to check it later, but if any user agrees with you, i mark your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

**SystemNavigator.pop()** will work for Android but it won't work in Ios side.

and

**exit(0)** will work for both systems but is not recommended because Ios may reject your app due to their guidelines and in Android, it stops the Dart VM process