# Getting a black screen when navigating between two pages in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

This is my home page code:

```
routes: {
    '/second' : (context) => addExpence(),
  },
```

my second-page code is:

```
FlatButton(
            child: Text("Done".toUpperCase()),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
```

please note that both pages are in different files. Now the problem is that I am getting a black screen when popping from the First Page.

Answer (score 2):

It's a natural thing to get a black screen when you pop from the `first page` because the `Navigator` will be empty. The only reason you're popping the `first page` is probably to close your app, for which you should use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-programmatically-closing-the-app).

Comment: but how will you be able to know that that method should be used to exit the app? override the back button event and check if it is the top screen?

Comment: @chitgoks for me , if  Navigator.of(context).canPop() is true call Navigator.of(context).pop() ,otherwise SystemNavigator.pop()

Answer (score 0):

@Lewis Weng's answer is the correct one that works for me too.

```
if(Navigator.canPop(context)){
   Navigator.of(context).pop();
}else{
   SystemNavigator.pop();
}
```