# Pop until there is no more root (i.e exit the app)

Tags: flutter

i am trying to use the navigator's popUntil method to exit my app so i was thinking if there was a way to pop all previous pages including the firstPage/route and cause the app to exit at this point. e.g The following code would pop all pages until firstPage which is my base route but how do i pop this page too.

```
    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/firstPage'));
```

Comment: Do you simply want to kill your application?

Comment: More like exit not kill

Comment: Just to clarify; How do you distinguish between exit and kill?

Comment: Use SystemNavigator.pop().
This is duplicate of this <https://stackoverflow.com/q/45109557/7807311>

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work by calling

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

just to be clear `exit(0);` also works but is not best practice and might probably give your ios app some issues when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```dart
import 'dart:io';`
() {
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/firstPage'));
exit(0);
}
```

And this could work:

```dart
() {
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/firstPage'));
Navigator.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close the app just call exit(0) on the event.