# How to force stop any application in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

I need to make a mobile application in which we can force stop any app, using Flutter.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)?

Comment: Tokenyet there is difference between exit app and force stop, in exit app only we closed app it's running in background and consuming internet all access and  in force stop it's vice versa...