# How to use systemNavigator.pop in below code to exit app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code. I used SystemNavigator.pop but it says `undefined name SystemNavigator`

**All I want is to exit the app using  OnTap**

```
class AppDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),
          _createDrawerItem(
              icon: Icons.home,
              text: 'Home',
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()),


          Divider(),

          _createDrawerItem
(icon: Icons.exit_to_app, text: 'Exit app',
onTap: () => SystemNavigator.pop),

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

What is the proper method to add `SystemNavigator.pop` in this case? Please help me if you know any method to add `SystemNavigator.pop`

Comment: Maybe you need parenthesis `SystemNavigator.pop()`

Comment: Wouldn't you just use Navigator.Pop()?

Comment: I want to exit APP

Comment: check this answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

Comment: it worked after importing flutter/service

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might be missing an import containing SystemNavigator, so add:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

You are missing a parenthesis, so, correct `SystemNavigator.pop` to
   `SystemNavigator.pop()`

Alternatively, you can use `SystemChannels`:

```
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>('SystemNavigator.pop');
```

instead of `SystemNavigator.pop()` inside `onTap`. Refer flutter documentation here: [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html)

Flutter documentation in the above link says:

> Instructs the system navigator to remove this activity from the stack
>   and return to the previous activity.
>
> On iOS, calls to this method are ignored because of Apple's human
>   interface guidelines state that applications should not exit
>   themselves.
>
> This method should be preferred over calling dart:io's exit method, as
>   the latter may cause the underlying platform to act as if the
>   application had crashed.

Never use `exit(0)` if you are planning to launch the app on the Apple app store as Apple Human Interface guidelines strongly discourage to exit the app programmatically. [Refer to this iOS documentation archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007952).

The above link says:

> Do not call the exit function. Applications calling exit will appear
>   to the user to have crashed, rather than performing a graceful
>   termination and animating back to the Home screen.

[Flutter documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-io/exit.html) on exit() says:

> Exit the Dart VM process immediately with the given exit code.
>
> This does not wait for any asynchronous operations to terminate. Using
>   exit is therefore very likely to lose data.

Comment: I NEED TO IMPORT  flutter/services.dart        except this everything is ok

Comment: doesnot work on ios simulator. doesnot test on real iphone.

Comment: @AkbarPulatov as mentioned in the answer Flutter ignores this command in iOS to comply with Apple's Human Interface guideline. 

"On iOS, calls to this method are ignored because of Apple's human interface guidelines state that applications should not exit themselves."

Comment: What's the advantage of `SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop')` over `SystemNavigator.pop();`?

Comment: Does SystemNavigator.pop() wait for sync operation to complete ? Or my real question is there a way to move hte async operation to the background and close the app when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemNavigator/pop.html

If you are trying to link a flutter module to an existing iOS app, then you will have to do the following modification to the ViewController Class.

Change 
`class ViewController: UIViewController {}`

to 
`class ViewController: FlutterViewController {}`

This should work if you use
`SystemNavigator.pop();`