# How to use back button function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I want to back programmatically without press back button , ("trigger back button functionality without pressing it ") ?

Comment: `Navigator.pop(context)` ?

Comment: I don't use stack of navigation , so If trigger this function in the root page the app will crashes because the back button functionality here is to close the app .

Comment: What kind of navigation are you using then ? Some code would help.

Comment: I think this will help you to figure out [programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534684/4954386)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use WillPopScope class for this case

```dart
bool shouldPop = true;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope (
    onWillPop: () async {
      return shouldPop;
    },
    child: const Text('WillPopScope sample'),
  );
}
```

Hope this helps. You can read more in the official documentation
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html