# Flutter back button

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added following code to my main screen in order to exit app after 2 times back button taps

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      final timeGap = DateTime.now().difference(preBackpress);
      final cantExit = timeGap >= const Duration(seconds: 2);
      preBackpress = DateTime.now();
      if(cantExit){
        const snack = SnackBar(
          content: Text('Press Back button again to Exit'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
      }
    },
    child: Scaffold(....)
  );
}
```

But what I get instead is that when I hit back button it goes all the steps back to every single screen user has been visited.

The reason I added `WillPopScope` above was to avoid going back to visited screen and just close the app but it seems still doesn't help.

**My question is:** How do I exit app (when in main screen back button is tapped) without going back to visited screens?

Comment: see related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the same as your code. but I have code to close apps as you want

```
class ExitController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExitControllerState createState() => _ExitControllerState();
}

class _ExitControllerState extends State<ExitController> {
  static const snackBarDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 2000);
  // set how long the snackbar appears
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  DateTime? backButtonPressTime;

  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    // margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 0, 75, 250),
    // add margin so that the snackbar is not at the bottom
    duration: snackBarDuration,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    content: Text('Press Again to Exit',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12)),
  );

  Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

    bool backButtonCondition =
        backButtonPressTime == null ||
            currentTime.difference(backButtonPressTime!) > snackBarDuration;

    if (backButtonCondition) {
      backButtonPressTime = currentTime;
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
        child: yourPageClass(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The snackbar will appear for 2000 milliseconds and during that time if the user press the back button again, the application will exit

Note to call **ExitController** class in main.dart, and wrapping your all structure(navigation class/page class/etc) with this **ExitController** class.
Example:

> main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_name/structure.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ExitController(),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: It still does the same (going to previous screens) the only difference is that it needs 2 times back button to show previous screens! :/

Comment: Where did you put the WillPopScope?
Did you put WillPopScope as parent and above all classes?

Comment: Yes, same structure as your sample code

Comment: Does your question mean when the user has moved to the second page from the first-page, users can close the application even though they are on the second-page?

Comment: I'm sure this problem occurs because of the class structure that you create or because of the way you wrap your class structure. not because of the code you attached.

Comment: no, I mean: `page one ->page two->page one->close`    currently is like: `page one->page two->page one->page two->page one->close`

Comment: When I back to page one from any page, it should be closed not to be back to those pages again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239144/discussion-between-septian-dika-and-mafortis).

Comment: Can I assume that you are not using the navigation bar?. If yes. Please update your question and attach the code of first page and second page.

Answer (score 0):

```
WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return await showDialog(context: ctx, builder: (_) => exitAlertDialog(_));
        },
        child: GestureDetector(onTap: () => FocusScope.of(ctx).unfocus(), child: widget));

Widget exitAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: plColor2,
    content: Text('Are you sure you want to exit?'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(child: Text('No'), onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false)),
      TextButton(child: Text('Yes, exit'), onPressed: () => SystemNavigator.pop())
    ],
  );
}
```

or you can use showsnackbar as your need

Comment: Showing snack bar is not my problem, please read the question