# How to actively crash Flutter app on Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-exception

The requirement is to exit the app when the button is clicked. I created a MethodChannel to do this. Using the principle of array out of bounds, respectively on both sides of the array out of bounds, crash on iOS but on Android is only an exception. I think this may be the mechanism of flutter, how to deal with this problem, or other methods.

Exception is:  E/flutter (16372): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, length=3; index=200, null,

Comment: On Android (via `MethodChannel`) you can use `throw RuntimeException()`.

Comment: Have yout tried to terminate the app (simulate a crash) using exit(0) in the exception. Does this fit your needs?

Comment: Try this to exit the app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see it before. That solves the problem