# Is it possible to manually control the flutter AppLifeCycleState?

Tags: flutter, application-lifecycle

Is it possible to manually control the flutter AppLifeCycleState?

```
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        debugPrint("Colorun - resumed");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        debugPrint("Colorun - inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        debugPrint("Colorun - paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        debugPrint("Colorun - detached");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to change the flutter app from running state to paused state?

Comment: These states is a callBack, a consequence of the user action. You want to control it programmatically?

Comment: @mariofrancois I want to control it programmatically. Do you know any way?

Comment: Any things here doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app

Comment: @mariofrancois thankyou!!!!! 
This is similar to what I was looking for.