# Flutter Ios how to exit app without exit(0)?

Tags: ios, flutter

Hi im tryng to exit with button. I know that using exit(0) is not recommended. I have tried SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'); but it didnt worked also any reccomendations ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use exit(0), then the app seems to be crashed. That is the reason Apple doesn't recommend the implementation of exit(0) explicitly.

If you want to exit with a button tap, then please add an alert to the user that why you have to restrart/exit the application. Therefore, users will be alerted why the app will misbehave with them.

Comment: hi what should I try I tried.  SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop'); but it doesn't work with iOS

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**

SystemNavigator.pop(): Does **NOT WORK**

exit(0): Works but Apple may **SUSPEND YOUR APP**

Please see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: ı checked here already