# How do I close my Flutter app programmatically on iOS?

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, application-restart

I want to close my Flutter my app programmatically, I have tried all available solutions they work pretty well for Android but do not work for iOS.

Below code works well for Android but not for iOS

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                  print('object'); 
                });

                
              },
              child: Text('Restart')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

`exit(0);` will work, if you want to both exit (pop) and terminate the app. Not the most elegant user experience, but some apps do do it.

Comment: Apple will surely reject your app for this reason.

Comment: @UjjawalMaurya it depends on the app. it is not forbidden, some apps do do it. However, it is not usually in the realms of a good user experience, so it depends on what the intention of the app exit is.

Answer (score 0):

`iOS` doesn't allows app to close by itself. If you use `exit(0)`, Apple `will reject` your application because it terminates `DartVM` and looks like app just crashed.

Apple doesn't allows that.