# Exit application on press of IconButton in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, function, exit, iconbutton

How to permanently exit the application from IconButton in AppBar?
I set icon:

```
return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Your app'),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<HomeCubit>().closeAppUsingSystemPop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
```

and in Home_Cubit I have:

```
 void closeAppUsingSystemPop() {
    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
  }
```

After pressing the icon, it exits the application, but only once and stays in memory.

I would like the app to close completely when I press the icon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app) Read more than just the accepted answer. There are several answers that give additional info. One is on using e.g. `exit(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**But don't use SystemNavigator.pop() for iOS, Apple says that the application should not exit itself :)**

Below code will work on Android for both cases,I hope this helps.

```
if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
     Navigator.pop(context);
   } else {  
   SystemNavigator.pop();
}
```