# Is there a way that Flutter won't allow my app to install or run at different sizes?

Tags: android, flutter, size, flutter-dependencies, responsive

I have coded an application that I have only optimized for the size of the phone (it is responsive on the phone). Now I want it not to be run or installed when the user runs it with the emulator on the computer?! is there a way
I have made my software responsive with package sizer.

I did this so that the software does not rotate, But I don't know how to make it display only for android resolution.

```
void main() {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: you can check on runtime using MediaQuery or just LayoutBuilder at top widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the device height / width / resolution  at runtime using MediaQuery.
If the current device's resolution is not as per your app's preference you can show some alert message to the user like :

`App is only optimized for mobile devices`

And upon closing the modal exit the app programmatically using `exit(0)`

Just for reference
[Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)