# Flutter how to kill/ destroy complete fluter app on single click from inside

Tags: flutter, dart

I want code for flutter app in which there will be one button in that app 'Destroy' and when i click on that button that app should be deleted from device with data and cache so I need code for such implentation.

Expected get full code with successfull implemntaion.

Comment: you cannot directly delete an app from a device with a "Destroy" button. This level of control is generally not allowed due to security and privacy concerns on mobile platforms. Users have the authority to uninstall apps, but apps themselves cannot initiate their own removal.

Comment: This link can help you resolve your query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app

Comment: Ohhk then I how to delete all data and cache data in a single click

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

```
await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
```

You cannot delete OR remove an app with the click of a button within the app.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer of my own question here is how we can kill/uninstall app programmatically in single click in Flutter:

1. Add package: `android_intent_plus: ^4.0.3` and `url_launcher: ^6.2.1`
2. Add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES"/>`
   in `androidmanfiestfile`

Code:

```
final packageName = 'add your own package here'; // Replace with your app's package name
final intent = AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.intent.action.DELETE',
    data: 'package:$packageName',
    package: packageName,
    flags: <int>[Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK],
);
await intent.launch();
```