# stop flutter_background_service when app is killed flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-background

How can I stop the [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) when the app is killed by the user?

```
final _androidConfiguration = AndroidConfiguration(
   onStart: _onStart,
   autoStart: true,
   isForegroundMode: true,
   initialNotificationTitle: 'App is running',
   initialNotificationContent: '');
final _iosConfiguration = IosConfiguration(
   autoStart: true,
   onForeground: _onStart,
);
```

`_onStart` is just a test for now.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void _onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on(BackGroundServiceOperations.setAsForeground).listen((event) {
    service.setAsForegroundService();
  });

  service.on(BackGroundServiceOperations.setAsBackground).listen((event) {
  service.setAsBackgroundService();
 });
}

 service.on(BackGroundServiceOperations.stopService).listen((event) {
 service.stopSelf();
});

  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
    debugPrint("background service is running!");
 });
}
```

I still get the `background service is running!` print when I kill the app.
If the app is closed normally (user confirm via the alert dialog that their want to close the app) I call

```
final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
var isRunning = await service.isRunning();
if (isRunning) {
  service.invoke(BackGroundServiceOperations.stopService);
}
```

and the background service stops, as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In your top widget, make it a `StatefulWidget` and add `WidgetsBindingObserver`:

```dart
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver { // (1) Use this mixin
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); // (2) Add this line
  }

  // (3) Add this overriding method
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      // (4) Add one of the methods to stop background service; see below
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this); // (5) Add this line
    super.dispose();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now, there are options to stop the background service:

- `backgroundService.invoke('stopService')`, with `backgroundService` being an instance of `FlutterBackgroundService` and `stopService` is a method that calls `service.stopSelf();` inside the entry `onStart` callback ***)**
- `exit(0)` (may be dangerous: see reasons from the answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45109557/13625293))
- Other methods that can kill isolates or stop the service

While using `exit(0)` can be dangerous and not a good practice to have, I found out (in my case) that this is the only method that works.

Also it might be a good idea to implement a logic that checks if the app is actually detached as a result of a normal exit (in your case, when the user confirms via alert dialog), so that this method is only called when really necessary.

---

***)** Example implementation:

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });

  // ...
}
```

---

See also:

- [GitHub Issue: Kill Service when app is killed](https://github.com/ekasetiawans/flutter_background_service/issues/238)
- [Flutter how to programmatically exit the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109557/flutter-how-to-programmatically-exit-the-app)

Comment: Which `AppLifecycleState` corresponds to app being killed?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. It's `detached`

Comment: Also it might be a good idea to implement a logic that checks if the app is actually detached as a result of a normal exit (in your case, when the user confirms via alert dialog), so that this method is only called when necessary

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. The service keeps running.

Comment: Check if the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method is firing with `detached` state when the app is killed; also try to deliberately call `exit(0)` with some button to see if it actually works

Comment: `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method is firing with`detached` state when the app is killed. I have the feeling that the method called for stoping the service is just ignored.