# SystemNavigator.pop() not being called in notificationTapBackground()

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to create notifications with actions.

```
final _notificationDetailsWithActions = NotificationDetails(
   android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
   notificationChannel.id,
   notificationChannel.name,
   channelDescription: notificationChannel.description,
   importance: notificationChannel.importance,
   priority: Priority.high,
   actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
   const AndroidNotificationAction('id_exit', 'Exit',
      cancelNotification: true),
  ],
 ),
  iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(
  presentAlert: true,
  presentSound: true,
  presentBadge: true,
  sound: 'notification.wav',
 ),
);
```

then I have

```
await _flutterLocalNotifications.initialize(
  settings,
  onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
      (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  },
  onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
);
```

and

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  // ignore: avoid_print
  debugPrint(
  'notification(${notificationResponse.id}) action tapped, actionId: 
  ${notificationResponse.actionId}');
  if (notificationResponse.actionId == exitActionId) {
    debugPrint('close app');
    SystemNavigator.pop();
  }
}
```

For some reason `SystemNavigator.pop();` is never called. Basically I want to close the app as well as a background service that I have running.

Comment: I think it's only callable from UI isolate. Maybe you can consider using `exit(0)` if really needed (by take cautions as mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78042265/13625293))